# Passing dynamic content inside a SQL Query in lookup stage of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using a lookup stage as a source to fetch some data and i want to pass that output as the input to the next lookup stage. I tried adding @activity('Step1').output.firstRow.Col and it failed with scalar variable was not being declared. Also tried with @{activity('Step1').output.firstRow.col} which failed and the log shows only default expressions supported. Please help if it is possible.

I have accomplished this using dataflow, but considering the performance i would like to know if it can be done in a pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this：

Query:`select * from dbo.test5 where col = '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.col}'`

[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Steve !! Worked as expected.